# lookup column list view threshold

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am experiencing a problem regarding lookup columns.

So the problem is that i have a list (list X), with a lookup column pointing to relating documents (list Doc). The X list itself is sitting at 400 items, but the Doc list is all ready sitting at 5200 items.

Now the lookup column which was pointing to the documents ID's is no longer working.

[image]

Is there a work around for this problem as i am aware that the Doc list item limit threshold can't be increased and to make use of views limiting the list is also out of the question as lookup columns can't point to a specific view.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here for your Doc list (the one with 5000+ items):

- Put items into folders with less than 5000 each
- Create an index on one of the columns
- Enable managed metadata navigation (creates indexes)

Actually, limiting the views to 5000 items would NOT help anyways.